# count of elements concatenated in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a concatenated range of values. I am trying to get the number of elements concatenated by looping over the range `B2:B` to identify the count of elements if are 3.

The loop should check if there are 3 elements then push those values into an array, if encountered 1 element then should break out.

```
function test(){
   d1= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var P_Details = d1.getSheetByName("test1");
   var P_range = P_Details.getRange("B2:B");
   var P_val = P_range.getValues();
   
   P_dump = [];
   for (var i in P_val){
     if(// (code here to split and count)=3){
         P_dump.push(P_val[i]);
     }
     else{ 
     break;
     }
   }
}
```

[image: image of the range]

|  | Concatenated values |
| --- | --- |
|  | a-b-c |
|  | a-d-e |
|  | w-x-y |
|  | d |
|  | d |
|  | e |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
   P_dump = [];
   for (var i in P_val){
     if(P_val[i][0].split('-').length == 3){
         P_dump.push(P_val[i][0]);
     }
     else{ 
      break;
     }
   }
   console.log(P_dump);
```